# $K(H)^{**}= B(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Is it true that we have an isometric linear isomorphism
$$B(H) \cong K(H)^{**}$$

where $K(H)^{**}$ is the bidual of the compact operators on $H$.

I think I proved this but I could not find a reference on the internet.  Is the result true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is completely standard and should appear in any operator theory book. One can easily show that $K(H)^*$ can be identified with $T(H)$ (the trace-class operators) via the duality
$$
\langle T,S\rangle=\operatorname{Tr}(TS).
$$
And similarly, $B(H)$ can be seen as the dual of $T(H)$ via the same duality.

To mention a few references:

- Conway, *A Course in Operator Theory*: Section 1.19
- Conway, *A Course in Functional Analysis*: Exercise IX.2.21
- Farenick, *Functional Analysis*, Theorems 10.99 and 10.102
- Reed-Simon, *Methods of Mathematical Physics. Functional Analysis*, Theorem VI.26
- Davidson, *C$^*$-Algebras by Example*, Exercises I.18 and I.20
- Murphy, *C$^*$-Algebras and Operator Theory*, Theorems 4.2.1 and 4.2.3
- Takesaki, Theory of Operator Algebras, Theorem II.1.8

Comment: Weird that I couldn't find a quick reference.

Comment: On a first look, it is mentioned in the [Wikipedia page for trace-class operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class#Trace_class_as_the_dual_of_compact_operators).

Comment: Yes it follows from that but the BIduality I couldn't find.

Comment: A bit unexpected for me, but when you think about it knowing the double dual of $K(H)$ is not that interesting, as is knowing its dual (which gives the weak topology) and the predual of $B(H)$ (which gives the weak$^*$-topology, usually called $\sigma$-weak operator topology).

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the help! I love duality results!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: I included a few references, since that was the actual question.

Comment: @Martinr Argerami You have helped me in the past with questions from Murphy's book on $C^*$-algebras. Maybe you can help me here too if you are interested/have time: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3811585/example-2-5-1-murphys-c-algebras-and-operator-theory-about-multiplicat Thanks!